# LED strip works through Arduino PWM, but not Raspberry Pi PWM

Tags: raspbian, gpio, led, arduino, pwm

I've been stuck on this for a while. I'm following a [simple tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-wiring) for RPi-controlled LEDs. From this, my LEDs do random stuff and don't light up correctly. I've been trying [strandtest from this library's examples](https://github.com/rpi-ws281x/rpi-ws281x-python)

Compare that to using Arduino Uno with [FastLED](http://fastled.io/)'s examples. Everything works perfectly with Arduino.

I know that this question is vague, but it seems like it scares people off when I ask this question in a more specific way with a more detailed explanation about my setup.

I've tried RPi 2 B+ with Raspbian Stretch and RPi 3 B+ with Raspberry Pi OS from January 2021. Same exact result with both RPis.

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: Is the LED strip a 5V strip? Are you powering it separately?

Comment: If you are referring to NeoPixel type devices they DO NOT use PWM on either platform! (They use PCM.) It is possible to use the WS2812 with a suitable library on the Pi **BUT you need a level shifter** to get sufficient drive. I have used strandtest in the past, but the Adafruit code keeps changing - so I can't confirm current code.

Comment: It is a 5V strip with 150 LEDs that I am powering separately with a 5V 10A supply.
---
This is the LED strip that I am using: `ALITOVE 16.4ft WS2812B Individually Addressable LED Strip Light 5050 RGB SMD 150 Pixels Dream Color Waterproof IP67 Black PCB 5V DC`
---
I am using this level shifter `https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/1787/1787AHC125.pdf`, which is recommended by Adafruit